# Evaluating $\iiint\frac{xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}$ over $\{(x,\,y,\,z)\in[0,\,\infty)^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\le R^2\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Evaluate $$\iiint\frac{xyz\,dx\,dy\,dz}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}$$ for $a>b>c>0$ where $\Omega:=\{(x,\,y,\,z)\in[0,\,\infty)^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\le R^2\}$

What do we do with the denominator here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It seems like this is just u-sub, but one variable at a time. Start by letting $u=a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2$ and go from here. I'm working through it and it's a lot to type out, but it seems to be working!

Comment: The answer is of the form $R^5f(a,\,b,\,c)$. We can verify $f(a,\,a,\,a)=\frac{1}{40a}$ by evaluating$$\frac1a\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\phi\cos\phi d\phi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3\theta\cos\theta d\theta\int_0^Rr^4dr.$$These observations don't determine $f$ in general, but they constrain it with a sanity check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate in spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
&\iiint\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2}}\,dx\,dy\,dz\\
=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^R
\frac{r^4\sin \theta \cos\theta \sin^3\phi \cos\phi}
{\sqrt{ a^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi +c^2\cos^2\phi}}dr d\theta d\phi\\
=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2}
\frac{R^5\sin^3\phi \cos\phi \ \sin \theta }
{5\sqrt{ a^2\sin^2\phi+ c^2\cos^2\phi +(b^2-a^2)\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta}} d(\sin\theta)\ d\phi\\
 =& \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{R^5\left(\sqrt{c^2-(c^2-{b^2})\sin^2\phi}-\sqrt{c^2-(c^2-{a^2})\sin^2\phi}\right)\sin\phi}{5(b^2-a^2)} d(\sin\phi)\\
=&\ \frac{R^5(ab+bc+ca)}{15(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}
\end{align}